# call jQuery function from flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to call a jQuery function from my flash file, when clicking on a button.
I've tryed to search around stackoverflow and google with similar problems however i cannot resolve this.

FYI, i tested this both locally and online with no results.

Actionscript 3.0 call:

```
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    open_mc.buttonMode = true;
    open_mc.useHandCursor = true;

    open_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ClickFunc);
    function ClickFunc(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
    ExternalInterface.call("openContainer", "open_god_dammit");
    }
```

jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#eas_sidekick_container").hide();
        $("#eas_sidekick_container").css('width', '0px');

        function openContainer(open_god_dammit)
        {
            $("#eas_sidekick_container").show();
            $("#eas_sidekick_container").animate({
                width: '850px'              
            });
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollLeft: '850'
            });
        }   
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your openContainer function should be outside the inner jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#eas_sidekick_container").hide();
    $("#eas_sidekick_container").css('width', '0px');

});

function openContainer(open_god_dammit)
{
    $("#eas_sidekick_container").show();
    $("#eas_sidekick_container").animate({
        width: '850px'              
    });
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollLeft: '850'
    });
}
```

Comment: So i did, but nothing happens when i click my button :( | even tryed moving it inline the script, but still no effect

Comment: I've tryed for fun using it in firefox, and it pop ups saying "null" allthough im clueless why it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem finally, it was due to the way i embedded flash in the html.

Since i used swfobject somehow it don't work together when calling functions, also i moved as above the functions outside my document.ready call, so it was part of the solution.

So if you wanna call external jQuery functions do not use swfobject for embedding the flash in your html file.

Comment: locally it works like a charm, but when i try build it in the system i want the "template" in, nothing happens. I have a clue that the root changes after uploading it to the system. Is there a way i can define the absolute root via the as3 when calling the function?